# Swift: setObject a struct array on Parse

Tags: ios, swift, struct, parse-platform

I am using Swift & Parse.

I have this class :

```
public struct Order {
    public var item: String
    public var price: Double
    public var comment: String
}
```

I know I can store an array of Strings or Ints. Is it possible to store an array of Orders in Parse?

To store the data i use this code :

```
var team = PFObject(className: "team")

team.setObject(*list of Orders*, forKey: "Players")
```

Comment: I think you're going to need to make Order its own class on Parse. You probably want to do the same in your client code for clarity and consistency's sake instead of the struct.

Comment: I created on Parse a custom class "Order". I did the same on my swift file too. The error is gone but when I try to set and Order Object I get a 'lldb' error.

Comment: Yeah, you can't trade an object in your Swift code for an object on Parse. You are going to need to instantiate or query for a PFObject and set its properties based off class's instance variables. You should write a method to do something like this in your API client class that takes an instance of your class and updates / creates the corresponding class on parse using some kind of unique object identifier.

Comment: Ahh.. dont understand how to do this... Can u refer me to an example? Otherwise I have to find another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Developers can subclass PFObject for a more native object-oriented class structure. Strongly-typed subclasses of PFObject must conform to the PFSubclassing protocol and must call before [Parse setApplicationId:clientKey:] is called. After this it will be returned by PFQuery and other PFObject factories.

In plain English for the reasonable man:

**Swift**

```
class Order : PFObject, PFSubclassing
```

**Obj-C**

```
@interface Order : PFObject, PFSubclassing
```